# SQLAlchemy session.refresh() spawns new connections

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy for orm in my project. My problem is that every time i use session.refresh(obj) new db connection is used which are held until session.close() is called. 
So when i want to refresh multiple objects i quickly run out of connections.

Session maker:

```
session = session_maker()
try:
    yield session
    session.commit()
    for obj in session:
        session.refresh(obj)
except Exception as e:
    session.rollback()
    raise e
finally:
    session.close()
```

Usage:

```
with make_session(...) as session:
        for mapped in [self._mapper.map(obj) for obj in objects]:
            saved_entities.append(mapped)
            session.add(mapped)
        session.flush()
```

I am using refresh because i have columns that are filled on update and I want to return current values.

The curious thing is that when i do that:

```
for obj in session:
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(obj)
```

only two connections are used (which is fine) but the objects have no data.

Comment: I also tried `session.connection().close()` after the `session.refresh(obj)` but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Use scoped_session, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html

If you do, you will get the same session (connection ID) each time you request it. Also, you don't need to call refresh(): add() and flush() should be enough, the updated values should be available after the flush() and before the commit(), but only if you're using the same session ID (database transaction) to look them up (hence, you need a scoped_session).

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. As for the other proposal commit() purges the content of the objects, they are refreshed when I will try to access their fields. For me it is not happening because objects after commit are used outside the session. The curious thing is that i have tried to create minimal replicable example but when I have implemented the usage of sqlalchemy myself it worked fine.